# CKEditor Support for Microsoft Edge and/or Internet Explorer 11

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

where do I find the browser (or system) requirements for ckeditor 4.4.3, 4.4.8, and 4.5.9?

Kind regards,

Oliver

Comment: Not entirely sure this is an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [complete list of ckeditor browser support](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_browsers).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Dekel